# JRXML: Dynamic sorting fields

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using Netbeans and Tibco Jaspersoft to make a java beans based report.

I need to add links that toggle ascending and descending order to a column header so the fields below will sort accordingly. I'm using a sortField to sort a field now, but is there a way I can dynamically change the order?

Edit:
Working on it now, I can not tell if my boolean parameter is changing on click. If any one knows a way to confirm the behavior of a variable in Jasper, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

You could dynamically sort the rows in Java (based on the column header) before sending through to the report. This can simply be done using `Collections.sort(collection, comparator)` where the comparator will sort the rows based on your column headers.